I am setting up an apache/passenger/rails stack on a Redhat 7.9 server. Passenger works standalone but dies when called via Apache
I am running Rails 7.0.8 on a Redhat 7.9 server using Passenger 6.0.22 and ruby 2.7.4
I am able to get passenger to run standalone using:
bundle exec passenger start
But when I run using Apache (using "systemctl restart httpd") I get a passenger failure during the first page load.  The error is:
The Phusion Passenger(R) application server tried to start the web application. But the application itself (and not Passenger) encountered an internal error.

Error details from passenger log:
App 125780 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:382:in `activate_gem'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:546:in `running_bundler'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:399:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 125780 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'`

The specific failure point is (in file /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb, line 55 in bold):
    # If there are no unresolved deps, then we can use just try
    # normal require handle loading a gem from the rescue below.

    if Gem::Specification.unresolved_deps.empty? then
      begin
        RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.exit
        **return gem_original_require(path)**
      ensure
        RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.enter
      end
    end

I suspect that the environment when called from Apache is not quite correct. But the error logs are not showing the path (or absence of a path) that the "gem_original_require" is having a problem with.
I suspect that I could solve the problem if I could have a way to:

add a debugging message showing the path
have a list of gems to double check
have a list of environment variables to check

I have tried:

rvm reinstall 2.7.4
gem pristine --all
bundle install
gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module

I would consider upgrading ruby to 3 but our code base is large and would require considerable work before it would work with ruby 3.
Any suggestions would be very welcome.

I noticed your list of attempts does not include gem update --system or gem install bundler. I would recommend attempting both of these (one at a time) to see if this rectifies the issue given that the error is actually "cannot load such file -- bundler/setup". Posting the output of  passenger-config --ruby-command could also be useful

When you run as Apache you're running as a different user with different environment variables. This is often the issue.

the error message indicates that the application itself (not Passenger), encounters a problem. Are there any messages in log/production.log? Can you launch the application from the command line with RAILS_ENV=production rails c (from the root dir of the app)?

The suggestions were all good.  The actual problem was weird:  apparently the "yum install mod_passenger" command caused, as a side effect, ruby 2.0.0 to be installed as /usr/bin/ruby.  And apache/passenger was using /usr/bin/ruby as the ruby, rather than the specified ruby 2.7.4.  Rails 7 needs ruby 2.7 at a minimum, so failed. Symlinking /usr/bin/ruby to ruby 2.7.4 fixed the problem.  So, the problem is resolved although I am curious why the yum install of mod_passenger had this effect.
